# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been developing a webpage with bootstrap along with some additional styles. The problem is that the navbar is not collapsing in the mobile view. I think that my multiple css files are overlaping.
Can anyone suggest me the appropriate changes?
Thanks in advance.
My html and css codes are [here](http://pastebin.com/v5xSiyrE)

Comment: the above link is not opening up... could you verify and send the proper link ?

Comment: just verified. working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below solutions

1.Did you include **bootstrap.min.js** file in your page.

Add below in your file footer and try.

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

2.just try change order of loading css files, load your custom css first and bootstrap last.

3.Inspect Page and check for errors(If any path misses make them correct.)

*Include "JQuery" if you miss this. Because Bootstrap JS Needs JQuery for proper working. Must load above bootstrap js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Load your custom css  first and bootstrap css second. try this

Comment: Inspect and check, is there any error in your page , did you includes jquery?? ('bootstrap js' need jQuery to work properly)

Comment: Solved the error thanks. The jQuery was not loaded properly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You are welcome... and can you make a up-vote to notify this answer is useful.

Comment: @AjeshVC Sir maybe the one who posted this question didn't up-vote you. But I'll do it gladly. Thank you for this new kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-0="line-height:100px; height:100px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);" data-300="line-height:60px; height:60px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="fa fa-bars color-white"></span>
            </button>

             <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="line-height:50px" data-0="margin-top:20px;" data-300="margin-top:5px;">GrocShop
          </a></h1>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-0="margin-top:20px;" data-300="margin-top:5px;">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>                </li>
                <li><a href="#section-team">Team</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo** of your code](https://jsfiddle.net/wkcdkhLL/)

(hide the *Result* span of JSFiddle.net to be able to click on the *nav* button)

What was fixed:

- A style should be defined. `navbar-default` was added to the `div class="navbar ..."` that defines the *navbar*.
- The CSS for `.navbar-toggle` where disabled since they made the button to look like a dot.